# sklearn cross valid / cross predict

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I understand that **cross_val_predict / cross_val** trains n out-of-folds models and then aggragate them to produce the final prediction. This is done on the train phase. Now, I want to use the fitted models to predict the test data. I can use for loop to collect predictions on the test data and aggregate them but first I want to ask if there is a build-in sklearn method for this?

````
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, train_test_split

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
y_train_hat = cross_val_predict(lasso, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
y_test_hat = do_somthing(lasso, X_test)```

Thanks
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 models from your `cross_val_predict` are not saved anywhere, so you can't make predictions with them.  You can use instead `cross_validate` with `return_estimator=True`.  You'll still be left with three models that you'll have to manually use to make and aggregate predictions.  (You could in principle put those models into an ensemble model like `VotingClassifier`, but at least for now there is no `prefit` argument to prevent refitting your estimators.  There some discussion in [Issue 7382](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7382) and links from there.)